# webRTC issue converting from webm+wav to mp4

Tags: javascript, video, ffmpeg, webrtc, mp4

After I got my .webm video and my .wav audio I decided to join it into an .mp4 file container.

I followed the library of muaz-khan `ffmpeg-asm.js` to do this conversion but when It finished, I got the blob which apparently was empty of video but after I downloaded I could reproduce it on my windows media player.

This is the code I have created for this test: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DevStarlight/eu2h9467/)

Checking some other sources, I found that there is another guy who reported the problem directly to muaz-khan 1 month ago [webrtc-experiment.com](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/ffmpeg/merging-wav-and-webm-into-mp4.html) (Last comment).

I don't think it's a problem related to conversion, I rather think is much more a problem of codecs.

How could I solve this problem (if it's possible to solve it) in order to watch my videos?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no standardized way of packing VP8 (which is what is contained inside a webm container) in mp4. I am not familiar with `ffmpeg-asm.js` but my guess is that it simply ignores the video because there is no way of packing it inside an mp4 container.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , so I am here because I am also finding a similar solution . With what I have learned so far , MP4 parses in javascript are way to heavy . you ought to take the stream to a java progra( j2EE server like in a media relay architecture )  to import MP4 libs and convert . Unfortunately I have only been successful with recorded content so far .  I am still figuring out a way to do it realtime .